# Django: AttributeError: view object has no attribute 'kwargs'

Tags: django, formset, inline-formset

I am building a view that I am passing in a uuid from the url. However when I try to access the kwarg, I get a `"AttributeError: view object has no attribute 'kwargs'"` error.

In my template, I am passing a UUID:

```
create/97261b96-23b8-4915-8da3-a90b7a0bdc8e/
```

**The URL:**

```
re_path(
    r"^create/(?P<uuid>[-\w]+)/$",
    views.DetailCreateView.as_view(),
    name="detail_create"),
```

**The View:**

```
class DetailCreateView(SetHeadlineMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, InlineFormSetView):
    inline_model = Detail
    headline = "Create a Detail"
    form_class = DetailForm
    success_message = "Detail Added"
    template_name = "details/detail_create.html"

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        return Post.objects.get_subclass(uuid=self.kwargs.get('uuid'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DetailCreateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.model = self.object.__class__()
```

For context on what is happening -

- Post is a model that is an [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html) that other models (Product & Variation) inherit from.
- Both models Product & Variation have a manytomanyfield to Detail.
- Upon creating a Detail, I will be adding it to either the Product object or Variation object.
- To set the model for the InlineFormSetView, I am trying to use the UUID to query for the object and dynamically set that based upon the class of the object I am trying to create a Detail for.

**Question**

Any ideas why I can't access the kwargs which is being sent in the URL path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [`as_view`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L62) method `kwargs` and `args` attributes are assigned to the view after `__init__` method. So when you call `get_object` inside `__init__` it raises the error since `self.kwargs` is not assigned yet. To fix this error you can move

```
self.object = self.get_object()
self.model = self.object.__class__()
```

from `__init__` to `get_object`:

```
class DetailCreateView(SetHeadlineMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, InlineFormSetView):
    inline_model = Detail
    headline = "Create a Detail"
    form_class = DetailForm
    extra = 10
    success_message = "Detail Added"
    template_name = "details/detail_create.html"

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        self.object = Post.objects.get_subclass(uuid=self.kwargs.get('uuid'))
        self.model = self.object.__class__()
        return self.object

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DetailCreateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `self.request.query_params.get('uuid')`